# Why returning False?

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation

[image: Screen shot]

Can anyone explain the false?
I'm trying to grab co-efficient in front of X^2 I think. I say I think as I'm following my tutors example using his screenshot the only difference between his question and one I'm doing are coefficients in front of terms but for x^2 both mine and his are the same , 1.
Here is his for comparison

[image: Tutor screen shot]

I've tried clearing all the variables then retyping then reevaluating but I keep getting this output of False/2 .
Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can take a derivative of a function (f = x^2 + ...), but not of a logical equation (f = a... == b...).

Comment: Please post code,  not just images.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Ok but can you tell me how he was able to get a 1 returned while I got false/2, even though we both seem to have entered the exact same characters?

Comment: As just commented by @YvesKlett, it is much better to post code than screen shots.  Follow the guidelines in [meta1027](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-kind-of-input-and-output-code-styles-are-acceptable-in-se). Doing so will encourage more people to consider your question.

Comment: `Assumptions$` is not `$Assumptions`.  Generally it's much better to post *code*, not screenshots.

Comment: You actually can take the derivative of an equation, but you get an equation.  In your case you get `2 == 0`, which evaluates to `False`.  The whole differentiated equation is divided by `2`, so `(2 == 0)/2` evaluates to `False`.  (*Mathematica* does not divide both sides of an equation, when you divide an equation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you are trying to take the derivative of a logical equation, not of a function.

f = x^2 - 2 * 3^(1/2) x y + 3 y^2 - 8 * 3^(1/2) x - 8 y;

```
D[f, {x, 2}]
```

(* 2 *)  Correct.

```
g = x^2 - 2 * 3^(1/2) x y + 3 y^2 - 8 * 3^(1/2) x - 8 y == 0;

D[g, {x, 2}]
```

(* False *)  A "derivative" of a logical expression.

If you must retain your logical equation (which I don't recommend), put parentheses around the terms to define `f` properly:

```
(f = x^2 - 2 * 3^(1/2) x y + 3 y^2 - 8 * 3^(1/2) x - 8 y) == 0;

D[f, {x, 2}]
```

(* 2 *)

Comment: Ah I see it now, as I put in, mistakenly, == this is it thank you.